# Paragraph header

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs, text-decorations

I want to include an indented, underlined, upper- and lowercase paragraph heading ending with a period in my document instead of using `\subsubsection`. Anyone who knows how I can define the command for this in LaTeX?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package; the `ulem` package was used for the underlining:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{15pt}{\uline{\theparagraph\hspace*{1em}#1.}}
\titleformat{name=\paragraph,numberless}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{15pt}{\uline{#1.}}

\begin{document}

\section{A Section}
\subsection{A Subsection}
\subsubsection{A Subsubection}
\paragraph{A Numbered Paragraph}
\lipsum[2]
\paragraph*{An Unnumbered Paragraph}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just noted that when I include the 'explicit' in titlesec package the section/subsection disappears and I end up with something like this 1 or 1.1 instead of '1 A Section' or '1.1 A Subsection'

Comment: @Thembi when the `explicit` option is used you need to use explicitly pass the title as #1 in the last mandatory argument, so, for example, instead of just saying `\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}` you need to use
 `\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{#1}`. If you experience any problems, please add to your question a minimal, complete example illustrating your problems.