# What's the difference between \paragraph and \paragraph*?

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs, starred-version

Is there any difference between `\paragraph{}` and `\paragraph*{}`?

When it's used (if nothing has been modified before, i.e. like in this post: [Paragraph header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67348/paragraph-header)), there's no difference in the created PDF file.

Normally, the `*` is used to prevent LaTeX to count/number the related object (paragraph here). But here, there's no count/numbering at all for both of them, thus... What's the change, if there is any at all?

Comment: Try to set `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}` and then you can see the difference.

Comment: Indeed, there counted. Still. You had to "modify" something to have it (and it's not pretty to look, unless it's use has "subsubsub" section). Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like with all sectioning commands from `\section` and lower (in the standard document classes), they are defined in terms of `\@startsection`, which allows for a starred variant. Taken from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx) (with emphasis/comments added):

```
\def\@startsection#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
  \par
  \@tempskipa #4\relax
  \@afterindenttrue
  \ifdim \@tempskipa <\z@
    \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa \@afterindentfalse
  \fi
  \if@nobreak
    \everypar{}%
  \else
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace\@tempskipa
  \fi
  \@ifstar%  <------------------------------------------ Condition on *
    {\@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}%  <----------------------- starred-version
    {\@dblarg{\@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}}}%  <----- regular/non-starred version
```

The difference only becomes noticeable when looking at the inner workings of `\@ssect` and `\@sect` - the choices after conditioning on `*` - the former associated with the starred-version. The main differences include:

- Numbering, based on the value of the counter `secnumdepth`. For `\paragraph`, this is 4. Setting `secnumdepth` to anything higher than or equal to 4 would reveal the difference;
- Inclusion in the ToC. Regardless of the value of `tocdepth` - the counter deciding which sectional units to include in the ToC, the entry is written to the `.toc` file. Only upon reading the `.toc` file is it decided to include the entry or not, based on the value of `tocdepth`.
- The running heads is triggered by `\paragraphmark` (when calling `\paragraph{..}`), initially set to `\@gobble`. So, without any modifications, this just gobbles its argument - the "paragraph title" and changes nothing in the heading. However, a suitable definition of `\paragraphmark` would show a different effect when using `\paragraph` as opposed to `\paragraph*` where no `\paragraphmark` is called.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to "reveal" the ToC inclusion ? And what about  the Running headers ?

Comment: the toc includes section levels down to  the `tocdepth` counter so as for numbering you just have to set `tocdepth` to 4 or above. The running heads from this level would be set by \paragraphmark, but by default this is `\@gobble` so it doesn't affect the heading.